# how does (i >>> -distance) work

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

this is the implecation of  rotateLeft in Long:

```
public static long rotateLeft(long i, int distance) {
   return (i << distance) | (i >>> -distance);
}
```

but,i can't understand how does (i >>> -distance) work! somebody who can tell me how! thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only the lowest bits of the shifting value are taken.

This is the same as

```
return (i << (distance & 63)) | (i >>> (-distance & 63));
```

or

```
return (i << (distance & 63)) | (i >>> ((64-distance) & 63));
```

or

```
return (i << distance) | (i >>> (64-distance));
```

---

One reason to use a negative number is that it works regardless of type so you can safely change it in the future.

e.g.

```
// This works regardless of whether `x` is `int` or `long` 
// and you can safely change the type in the future.
// 1 if negative, 0 if non-negative
x >>> -1;

// works for 32-bit but not 64-bit so if you change the type later,
// it could break without compiler error.
x >>> 31;
```

You might find this interesting http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2012/01/shifting-challenge.html

Comment: thank you! that is the jvm will turn -distance to (-distance & 63) when compiling ? is that right?

Comment: No, its how the JVM implements it, positive or negative.  Even `1L << 64` becomes `1L`

Answer (score 0):

`>>>` is the [unsigned right shift operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

> The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position.

Comment: I think the OP would like to know how shifting by a negative number works.